# .NET Core - Dependency Injection without constructor or method params drilling

Tags: .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

How to satisfy a constructor signature of a class `SomeValidation` with `IRepo` with an in-built IoC container in .NET Core when instantiating the class `SomeValidation` in `SomeOtherClass`? Is there a way to tell to a concrete instance of a class `SomeValidation` in `SomeOtherClass` that `IRepo` will be injected by IoC container and NOT by me?
To better understand the problem please see the following example:

```cs
public class SomeValidation<T>
{
    //I want this dependency to be injected and resolved by the DI container 
    //and I do not want to drill down though other classes to the controller. 
    //IRepo is registered in IoC container with IServiceCollection in Startup.cs 
    //like services.AddScoped<IRepo, Repo>();
    private readonly IRepo _repo;
    private T _entity;

    public SomeValidation(T entity, IRepo repo)
    {
        _entity = entity;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    void ValidateIsNotNull()
    {
        if (_repo.Get<T>(_entity.Id) == null)
            throw new Exception("Entity not found");
    }

    void Validate()
    {
        ValidateIsNotNull();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    // Constuctor is empty and I want to keep it that way
    public SomeOtherClass()
    {
    }

    //I do not want to inject dependency as a method param either.
    //I do not want to use service locator (anti)pattern as well, so having
    // IServiceProvider as an additional param also does not work for me.
    public void SomeMethod(T entity)
    {
        // I want this dependency to be injected and resolved by the DI container and
        // I do not want to drill down to the controller to inject this dependency.
        var validation = new SomeValidation<T>(entity, **WHAT TO PASS HERE ???**);
        validation.Validate();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Constuctor is empty and I want to keep it that way". Can you elaborate on this? Why do you need/want the ctor to be parameterless?

Comment: Note that your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you improve your question we might be able to give more satisfactory answers that solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @Steven, so people do not suggest me ideas about injecting IRepo into SomeOtherClass constructor and then use it for SomeValidation(entity, repo) ;-) This would defeat the whole purpose of the question (drilling). Thanks for reformatting the question by the way.

Comment: I can't speak for others, but the only thing I'm suggesting is for you to rephrase your question in such way that you don't ask for a specific solution, but rather describe the underlying (design) problem you are trying to solve. Without understanding that, I myself will be unable to supply you with a good answer. I'm also unfamiliair with the concept of "drilling."

Comment: What about dependency injecting your SomeValidation instead?

Comment: Also why does SomeOtherClass have to have a parameterless constructor. You're already using dependency injection elsewhere. Just keep doing everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new instance without passing parameter try this!

```
var service = (SomeValidation)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SomeValidation));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem with this approach ("service locator pattern")  that it is considered by many as an **antipattern**. For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#recommendations. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: ValidateIsNotNull(); requires IRepo. You need to have an IRpo instance to pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can then add it it to your servicecollection for each type. If you create an interface that implements SomeValidation. Then it will be easier to do an assemblyscan that adds all those SomeValidation to your serviceCollection.

```
public class SomeValidation<T> : IValidation
{
    //We will use this as a key
    public Type ValidatorType = typeof(T);
    ...

}
```

Register the SomeValidation for your types.

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IValidation,SomeValidation<SomeType>>();
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IValidation,SomeValidation<SomeOtherType>>();
```

Then you can use @Vaduganatha's solution to just get the validator. Since IRepo gets dependency injected.

```cs
var service = (SomeValidation)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(SomeValidation));
```

But I much prefer the following solution. Since as you said it is an anti-pattern. But there are no solution that is parameterless. How would you ever get your validators or your IRepo if you don't pass it in some way. But I also think that the solution you thought you'd get would be that you dependecy inject IRepo into SomeOtherClass - which I find unnecessary. It's already dependency injected into your validators afterall. So now we just dependency inject your validators into SomeOtherClass.

```cs
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    private IDictionary<Type, IValidation> validators;
    public SomeOtherClass(IEnumerable<IValidation> validators)
    {
        this.validators = validators.ToDictionary(v => v.ValidatorType, va => va);
    }

    public void SomeMethod(T entity)
    {
        var validator = validators[typeof(entity)];
        validator.Validate();
    }
```

Footnote: You can register all your validations using an assemblyscan some what like this. Which is why I suggested making your validation to an interface.

```
private static void RegisterAllImplementations<T>(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    serviceCollection.Scan(s => s
        .FromAssemblyOf<T>()
        .AddClasses(c => c.AssignableTo<T>())
        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .WithScopedLifetime());
}
```